# CPPFLAGS set but a header is still not found

Tags: c++, compilation, configure, autoconf, openfst

I set both CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS with ./configure, but the header fst.h is still not found. Though it is located in the indicated in the CPPFLAGS directory.

```
./configure CPPFLAGS=-I/Users/username/Downloads/openfst-1.5.1/src/include LDFLAGS=-L/Users/username/Downloads/openfst-1.5.1/src/lib
```

...

```
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking fst/fst.h usability... no
checking fst/fst.h presence... no
checking for fst/fst.h... no
configure: error: Required file fst/fst.h not found -- aborting
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually set the `CPPFLAGS` environment variable which the `configure` script checks, but you pass `CPPFLAGS=-I/Users/username/Downloads/openfst-1.5.1/src/include` as an *argument* to the script. Same with `LDFLAGS`.

You should set them as an environment variables *before* the script, like

```
CPPFLAGS=-I/Users/username/Downloads/openfst-1.5.1/src/include LDFLAGS=-L/Users/username/Downloads/openfst-1.5.1/src/lib ./configure
```

Using line-continuation to make it easier to see all at once:

```
CPPFLAGS=-I/Users/username/Downloads/openfst-1.5.1/src/include \
LDFLAGS=-L/Users/username/Downloads/openfst-1.5.1/src/lib \
./configure
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I still get exactly the same error message